# How to find difference between two lists?

Tags: dart

There are two lists:

```
List<int> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
List<int> list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

How to find difference between them, i.e. [6,7] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dart
List<int> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
List<int> list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
List<int> filtered = list2.where((i) => !list1.contains(i)).toList();
```

Comment: note that `list.contains(e)` is a `O(n)` operation.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
main() {
  List<int> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9];
  List<int> list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  var list1WithoutList2 = list1.toList()..removeWhere(list2.contains);
  var list2WithoutList1 = list2.toList()..removeWhere(list1.contains);
  var diff = [...list1WithoutList2, ...list2WithoutList1];
  print(diff); // [9, 6, 7]
}
```

If you add 2 Sets as input you could have used [Set.difference](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Set/difference.html)